# Data storage for Android app

Tags: android

I need to write an application with a lot of questions with 4 variant aanswer for each (tests, in short). Where to store the actual answers and the questions? Create a file, or use SQLlite, or Strinq.xml (although it seems this is the most desirable not).

If I use SQLlite, then for example, if somebody download app, all of my questions and answers should already be there.

Comment: Is this an App where u ask ,lots of question  ? And now ur asking where to save these questions. If i am correct do tell me weather u have dynamic question or static question

Comment: Thanks for response, a lot of question and answer. Only static question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using SQLite. It will be easier from upgrade perspective and server sync

Comment: Thank you for response! As I understand from the documentation SGLlite mainly used to store user settings? But I need store only my data. For example, if somebody download app, all of my questions and answers should already be there.

Comment: Not really. For example all your contacts are stored in SQLite initially these are synced with Gmail and then also updated based on user actions.

Comment: Thanks again, but I think my english very bad :) How can I do it without internet access. User just download app, so all data, all answer, all question already in DB, file and etc. Its real, I know a lot of app with this functions, but dont know how them store the data.

Comment: Well you execute SQL statements first time an Activity in created on the phone, keep a boolean to check that this happens only once in the lifetime of an app

Comment: Ok, for example  if I use db.execSQL(data). Where I store the data (my answer and question) to execute? Execute from where? Where I should store my data to execute?

Comment: You will have to hard code in the code ..or some flat file in the app

Comment: Ok, I also think its solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use SQLlite.

Very easy to setup and you'll have all the power of a database in your app.

Comment: Thank you for response! As I understand from the documentation SGLlite mainly used to store user settings? But I need store only my data. For example, if somebody download app, all of my questions and answers should already be there.

Comment: No. You can store whatever you require. For populating the DB, you can inititalise the database on the first run with standard SQL statements.

Answer (score 2):

SQLiteis one option, but depending on amount of data you have to store, private  JSON file may be better one -  there are data binding frameworks which will convert it into objects without additional code

Comment: Thank you for response! As I understand from the documentation SGLlite mainly used to store user settings? But I need store only my data. For example, if somebody download app, all of my questions and answers should already be there.

Comment: SQLite is small in process SQL database.  It can be (mis)used to store settings  or whatever you like. However,  as all SQL datastores is has awkward interface, and returns you just tuples of data. If you need objects, and not thatmany objects ( say, up to 1000 ) you are better off with JSON and databinding framework.  Only advantage you get from SQL is querying

Comment: I created lightweight databinding  framework on top of google GSON: https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer  ( see unit tests how to use it) I use stripped down GSON, just pull parser ( som 10KB ) with it.   Framework is realeased and available from maven central

Answer (score 1):

You need to design your database which can store such information like below,

Table Name : Questions

field Name : qId ( Primary Key )
             question Text(100)
             answer1 Text (100)
             answer2 Text (100)
             answer3 Text (100)
             answer4 Text (100)
             correctAnswer Number(1)

however detail designing can add more fields in it.